# posting none-english data with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, html, localization, character-encoding, httpwebrequest

The web site is in hebrew with Windows-1255 encoding.
Using Firefox's Tamer Data extension, i see that one of the Post parameters is:
+++++++++%E4%FA%E7%E1%F8+++++++++
using [this](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepages.php?codepage=windows-1255) table  I translated it to hebrew:

+++++++++התחבר+++++++++

Now, I want to send it as post data:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

 string param =;// What should I set here? should i type in hebrew? should i conver it to hex?         
 //Should I type +++++++++%E4%FA%E7%E1%F8+++++++++   or maybe %E4%FA%E7%E1%F8?
 string postData = string.Format({0}={1}",param,value);
 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); //what encoding to use?          
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";           
 request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

 Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Safest way in my opinion is type it in hebrew, and use

`Uri.EscapeDataString(paramValue)` to escape the characters

```
string param = 'paramName';        
string value = 'התחבר';

string postData = string.Format("{0}={1}", param, Uri.EscapeDataString(value));
```

So in this case, it would be safe to use ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the content type `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, then you must encode the parameters in URL form (i.e. every byte that's not valid in a URL must be `%` + the hex code). The `+` becomes a space during decoding, btw.

To get the `byteArray`, use `ASCII` encoding (all characters in that array will have a code point < 128). In this case, `UTF-8` would also work because in this range, they match, but it would not should your intention.

Comment: I am still confused, in my case param should be: param="%E4%FA%E7%E1%F8" and I should use ASCII instead of UTF8?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you set the content type, you also specify the encoding of the content. If you fail to properly encode the content (it's just a byte array), then the receiver will fail to decode it. It would be more simple if you could pass a unicode string to the framework and have it figure out the encoding using the same rules the other side will use for decoding ...

Answer (score 0):

@dan you are correct,
its works very well

```
string scaprstring= Uri.EscapeDataString("unicode string" )`

 Uri.UnescapeDataString(scaprstring);
```